# Could we get more options/reasons for closing questions?

Tags: feature-request

Recently I posted a [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103682/does-nature-jump) on the PSE that initially gathered quite a few interesting responses and many cogent comments. I thanked contributors and approved the response I found the most precise and useful.

Then the debate entered another phase wich I would describe as essentially about nitpicking. It stopped being interesting and became tedious, at least in my opinion.

So I voted to close down my own question, to avoid muddling what I saw as a decent thread with too many weak responses. When I did so, I found that none of the options provided matched my concern. Now the question appears closed because "off topic". However, my question was demonstrably metaphysical and was understood as such by most contributors. I don't think it wasn't off topic.

I wonder if we could have additional options for closing down questions, as the present menu of options is quite narrow. Based on the above experience, I would propose the following additional option: "**The question has been answered to its author's satisfaction**".

I understand this would require a different process than the 5 votes to close, i.e. one single vote by the question author would suffice, possibly vetted by a mod.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big problem with what you suggest: *closed questions are less useful for other users because they may not show and may be subject to automatic deletions*.

The more elegant solution in such a case is to raise a flag and ask to **lock** a given post. This means that edits (or comments, if chosen) become impossible, possibly even permanently if one wants that. The tooltip even tells me to lock comment threads if the comments *stop being useful for the improvement of the post*.

Considering that closure does by no means stop comments (or even edits) from happening, it sounds veryuch like this is what you would have wanted in this case as well. Drop a comment and I can change it accordingly if you like me to.

Comment: Thank you for this; i guess i hadn't thought of all the consequences. Okay, that would work. Kindly do the needful.